# Free jqGrid - How to restore filter bar operators

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Suppose I have a filer toolbar filled up with the actual values and operators (ne, lt, etc').

Now, I want to unload this entire jqGrid, and re-create it all again but with the **same exact toolbar filters** (I have more than one reason for doing such, such as add/remove columns as I don't want to use the hidden, or even saving the grid last configurations on the browser DB).

Up till now, I thought that I can restore the toolbarfilter just by filling up again the postData.filters, and call to grid.setGridParam({ postData:sessionListData(grid,gridName)  });

This doesn't works so well, as I now discovered, that while it does filling back the values and also the operators, it's not applying the actual operators as it shows.

So, in the example below, the #Passed is showing >2 as the session is loaded.  But, as I will hit the enter key to get it post the data once again, it will send it as ==2 and not >2 since eq is the default.

What will be the best way to restore the filterTollbar so that it will also restore the operator, the value and the actual operator indication?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that `search: true` option is set if the restore non-empty filter (if `postData.filters` is not empty). You didn't posted your code so I can only guess. Moreover the moment **when** you restore the filter could be important. It should be *before* the current data returned from the server be processed. For example if you restore the filter from the server and you use `loadonce: true` then you can restore the filter inside of `beforeProcessing` callback.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  I do bring it back as "search: true", and don't have a loadonce:true.   It is important to mention that the first time the grid is loading, it does bring back everything as expected.  It is once I start and use the filters that the problem appears.

Comment: So:  (1) - the grid is loaded with the right data and all.  Then (2), I manually put the cursor into the filter box, and click on "enter" - at that time, the jqGrid (although) showing the > sigh, is sending "==" and not 
">".

Comment: @Tal: **when** (in which callback) you restore the filter? What is your test case? Where is your code/demo?

Comment: I'm restoring at gridComplete

Comment: var postData = JSON.parse(grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
   
   
   //To do - might be there is a need to switch between post and pre filter (probably not).
   postData["filters"] = gridsSettingObject[gridName].barFilter; 
   if (gridsSettingObject[gridName].advancedFilter){
    postData["afilters"] = gridsSettingObject[gridName].advancedFilter; 
   }
   
   
   grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData: postData });

Comment: @Tal: I wrote in my answer that it's **too late** you should do this inside of `beforeProcessing`. Can you reproduc any problem on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm)?

Comment: @Tal: Your last code contains `afilters`. What is that? Moreover it's important to see more full code or to debug it. If you suppose that jqGrid have a bug then you should prepare the demo and describe the test case which I can use to reproduce the problem.